# Slick Slider content wont snap back when resizing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the Slick-Slider as part of a responsive website. the problem is when you resize the browser the content panels in the slider will not swipe and gets stuck.

If you resize the browser to phone size and swipe to slide 5. Then resize the browser to full width.

You will see that you can no longer see slide 1 to 4 and the first slider will show on slide 5 onward.

HTML file code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="text-danger">Recommended For You / Latest Offer</h1>
            <div id="ig-offer" class="row">
                <div id="ig-offer-6-latest" class="slider responsive">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Account</div>
                            <img src="../../images/game/assassin.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Player of the Month: Messi</h5></div>
                                <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
                                    FIFA 15
                                    <br />
                                    Xbox ONE
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 103.90</b></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-cur">Currency</div>
                            <img src="../../images/game/ff-tactics.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">5,000 GOLD</h5></div>
                                <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
                                    1 Gold = RM 0.000703
                                    <br />
                                    Aegwynn - Alliance
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 23.90</b></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-itm">Item</div>
                            <img src="../../images/game/harvest-moon.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Legendary Weapon's Raw Materia</h5></div>
                                <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
                                    Guild Wars 2
                                    <br />
                                    All Servers
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 486.56</b></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-bss">Boosting</div>
                            <img src="../../images/game/hero.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">10,000 GOLD</h5></div>
                                <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
                                    1 Gold = RM 0.000703
                                    <br />
                                    Aegwynn - Alliance
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 48.50</b></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-crd">Card</div>
                            <img src="../../images/game/lol.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Legendary Weapon's Raw Materia</h5></div>
                                <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
                                    World of Warcraft
                                    <br />
                                    Firetree - Horde
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 263.10</b></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-cur">Currency</div>
                            <img src="../../images/game/reckoning.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Something of Something: Epicness</h5></div>
                                <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
                                    Guild Wars 2
                                    <br />
                                    All Servers
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 82.50</b></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

index.js :

```js
jQuery("div[id^='ig-offer-6-']").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 250,
    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    prevArrow: '<a class="slick-prev slick-nav slick-left" role="button" data-role="none"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="false"></span></a>',
    nextArrow: '<a class="slick-next slick-nav slick-right" role="button" data-role="none"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="false"></span></a>',
    responsive: [
        {breakpoint: 1024, settings: {slidesToShow: 3}},
        {breakpoint: 600, settings: {slidesToShow: 2}},
        {breakpoint: 480, settings: {slidesToShow: 1}}
    ]
});
```

The slick.js is a default javascript download from github.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put below script then can able to solve the solution.

```js
<script>
 var $slider = $('#your-element'); // my slider

 $(window).resize(function() {
      
 $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0);
     
 });
</script>
```

Ps* this is only for slider with no animation.